# If $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence of functions in a complete metric space, then does $\sup_{x\in X}d(f_n(x), f_m(x)) < \epsilon$ hold?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

Let $X$ be a set, $(Y, d)$ be a complete metric space, and $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of functions satisfying the Cauchy condition $\forall \epsilon > 0:\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}:d(f_n(x), f_m(x)) < \epsilon, \forall n, m \geq n_0, x \in X$. Then does it hold true that, similarly, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a large enough $N \in \mathbb{N}$ that $\sup_{x \in X}d(f_n(x), f_m(x)) < \epsilon, \forall n, m \geq N$? We certainly can force the distance to be less than epsilon at any singe point, and therefore at any finite subset of $X$. But I'm not sure how you could proceed with the proof.

The context of this question is, is that a given hint for the problem of showing that a function sequence being Cauchy in a complete metric space is equivalent for that sequence to converge uniformly, was to consider $\sup_{x \in X}d(f_n(x), f_m(x))$.

Comment: I don't understand this question: The way you write the Cauchy condition, for every $\varepsilon>0$ as well as $n,m$ large enough, we have $\forall x\in X: d(f_n(x), f_m(x))<\varepsilon$. But then of course we also have $\sup_{x\in X}d(f_n(x), f_m(x))\le\varepsilon<2\varepsilon$. Does this answer your question or is there something missing?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I believe it does!

Comment: If in the first statement we had for each $x$, $f_n$ satisfies Cauchy condition then we can say that $f_n$ converges pointwise (since $Y$ is complete) . Also the second statement implies $f_n$ converges uniformly.